# Vim misses a few files when opening multiple files

Tags: vim

I use `vim -o a*` to open 25 files (filenames starting with 'a') together and search & replace some common word in these files. Later I found that not all of them have been modified and it seems to be due to that `vim -o` opens only 23 of them. However, `vim -O a*` can open all 25 files.

So is there any safe way to make sure every file is opened (and thus modified), hopefully not by counting windows by eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Vim gets multiple file arguments on the command line it creates (unloaded) buffer for each of them. There's no need to supply `-o` or `-O`. Just use `:h :ls` to see all available buffers, and `:bnext`, `:bprev` to move between them in a single window.

Make sure you've read `:h windows-intro` to know the basics.